# umount a bind source won't work, and device out of space

Tags: linux, bind, mount, disk-space-utilization

I think I may have shot myself in the foot.  Long ago I tried to backup a old linux machine to a nas using the mount bind command:

mount --bind / /mnt/src
tar -C /mnt/src -c . > /mnt/backup_to_nas/full-backup-`date '+%d-%B-%Y'`.tar.gz --exclude=tmp --exclude=mnt

Then I realized I never umounted /mnt/src

My question is, is this taking up double the space on the / that I have?  I am woefully out of space and not sure if I am chasing my tail trying to delete files to recover space.

df -h shows:

```
[root@web-server mnt]# df -h
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                          1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                             1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             1.9G  194M  1.7G  11% /run
tmpfs                             1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda2                         7.6G  7.6G     0 100% /
/dev/vda1                         190M  171M  5.3M  98% /boot
/dev/vdb                          230G  152G   67G  70% /usr/local
tmpfs                             379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs                             379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/2527
tmpfs                             379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/2543
10.50.1.104:/data                 9.1T  8.0T  610G  94% /mnt/backup
tmpfs                             379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/2539
10.75.0.199://volume1/ICCBackups   32T  4.2T   28T  14% /mnt/backup_to_nas
tmpfs                             379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/500
```

lsblk shows:

```
[root@web-server mnt]# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda    253:0    0     8G  0 disk 
├─vda1 253:1    0   200M  0 part /boot
└─vda2 253:2    0   7.8G  0 part /mnt/src
vdb    253:16   0 232.8G  0 disk /usr/local
```

did a space check in root:

du -xhs * | sort -rh

```
134G    home
15G data
6.9G    mnt
186M    run
170M    boot
52M etc
848K    ARC-History.pdf
16K lost+found
8.0K    export
8.0K    backup
4.0K    media
4.0K    check_permissions.py
0   sys
0   proc
0   lib64
0   lib
0   dev
0   bin
```

I don't understand why some large folders like /home are bigger than what df -h reports so I did a mount | grep home and got:

```
[root@web-server mnt]# mount | grep home
/dev/vdb on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/vda2 on /home/weather/public_html/weather_rrd type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/vda2 on /usr/local/home/weather/public_html/weather_rrd type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/vdb on /home/workers/public_html/VM-SYSTEMS type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/vdb on /usr/local/home/workers/public_html/VM-SYSTEMS type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

It looks like if I could figure out what these are and how to relocate I might buy myself some breathing room:

```
/dev/vda2 on /home/weather/public_html/weather_rrd type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/vda2 on /usr/local/home/weather/public_html/weather_rrd type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Then again all this to say, did my mount --bind command of / into /mnt/src take up double space?  Is there something I didn't understand (probably) when doing this?  I did a lsof /mnt/src and it seems that everything is using it.

but did start with this to report not sure if its relevant:

```
[root@web-server mnt]# lsof /mnt/src
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() ext4 file system /var/www/html/net-status/bw-mon (deleted)
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() ext4 file system /usr/local/www/net-status/bw-mon (deleted)
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

So not sure where to start deleting large files as I find them in /? (even though it seems /home is somewhere else?). ls -lh doesn't show it as a symlink.

```
[root@web-server /]# ls -lh
total 1.2M
-rw-------    1 root root 847K Jul 27  2020 ARC-History.pdf
drwxr-xr-x    3 root root 4.0K Sep 13 17:21 backup
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root    7 May 11  2018 bin -> usr/bin
dr-xr-xr-x.   5 root root 3.0K Aug 16 18:06 boot
-rw-r--r--    1 root root 3.3K May 12  2019 check_permissions.py
-rw-------    1 root root    0 Sep 13 17:33 core.20448
-rw-------    1 root root    0 Sep 13 17:46 core.28055
drwxr-xr-x    7 root root 4.0K Sep 13 17:16 data
drwxr-xr-x   18 root root 3.1K Sep 12 18:08 dev
drwxr-xr-x. 148 root root  12K Aug 31 17:26 etc
drwxr-xr-x    3 root root 4.0K Apr  2  2015 export
drwxr-xr-x   22 root root 4.0K Aug 27 18:06 home
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root    7 May 11  2018 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root    9 May 11  2018 lib64 -> usr/lib64
drwx------.   2 root root  16K Mar 31  2015 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root 4.0K Apr 12  2018 media
drwxr-xr-x.   6 root root 4.0K Feb  9  2023 mnt
drwxr-xr-x.   7 root root 4.0K Aug 25 15:13 opt
dr-xr-xr-x  225 root root    0 Nov  8  2021 proc
dr-xr-x---.  26 root root  12K Aug 25 15:19 root
drwxr-xr-x   48 root root 1.5K Sep 13 17:01 run
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root    8 May 11  2018 sbin -> usr/sbin
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    0 May 15  2019 searchresults.txt
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root 4.0K Apr 12  2018 srv
dr-xr-xr-x   13 root root    0 Nov 29  2021 sys
drwxrwxrwt.  16 root root 244K Sep 13 17:49 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.  14 root root 4.0K May 11  2018 usr
drwxr-xr-x.  25 root root 4.0K Aug  9 20:21 var
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root 4.0K Aug  9  2015 zaphod-data
```

EDIT:
Looked at the fstab file that shed some light onto where stuff is:

```
UUID=c9d6c99f-d7a5-4117-93ba-029cc34d8b61 /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=19fcad32-0fcb-423a-87e9-586d03d2e406 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
#LABEL=/home    /home       ext4 defaults 1 2
#192.41.211.105:/export/images      /export/images          nfs     rsize=32768,wsize=32768,actimeo=0,bg,intr
LABEL=local-web-server  /usr/local  ext4    defaults    1 2
/usr/local/home     /home       none    bind        0 0
/usr/local/www      /var/www/html   none    bind        0 0
/usr/local/data     /data       none    bind        0 0
/tmp/rrdweather     /home/weather/public_html/weather_rrd   none    bind    0 0
/usr/local/data     /data       none    bind        0 0
/home/workers/Site/VM-SYSTEMS /home/workers/public_html/VM-SYSTEMS none bind 0 0
#/home/workers/public_html/WebCalendar-1.2.3 /home/workers/public_html/WebCalendar none bind 0 0
#/home/workers/public_html/WebCalendar-1.2.0 /home/workers/public_html/WebCalendar~ none bind 0 0
/home/workers/public_html/net-status /usr/local/www/net-status none bind 0 0
/tmp/bw-mon     /var/www/html/net-status/bw-mon     none    bind        0 0
/var/lib/smokeping/images /var/www/html/smokeping/images none   bind        0 0

#mounting for our cheezy backup of web-server
10.50.1.104:/data /mnt/backup nfs
```

Edit 2:  So I realized if I did the sort command in /mnt/src I get more accurate information....

```
[root@web-server src]# du -xhs * | sort -rh
4.8G    usr
707M    var
421M    opt
397M    backup
168M    root
150M    tmp
52M etc
848K    ARC-History.pdf
16K lost+found
12K mnt
8.0K    export
4.0K    zaphod-data
4.0K    sys
4.0K    srv
4.0K    run
4.0K    proc
4.0K    media
4.0K    home
4.0K    dev
4.0K    data
4.0K    check_permissions.py
4.0K    boot
0   searchresults.txt
0   sbin
0   lib64
0   lib
0   core.28055
0   core.20448
0   bin
```

Shows me maybe space to clear in usr (no idea what I am not a linux guru), var had some nice stuff I was able to clear out (old logs).   Still working on it but the crux I guess of what I am asking is should I really get that /mnt/src unmounted?  or is it okay letting it ride like this since everytime I try to issue the command it says its busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

`/mnt/src` is not taking space but you should unmount it to not confuse some tools, including tools doing backup. For example `lsblk` chooses to display the first matching mount and displays `/mnt/src` instead of `/` for `/dev/vda2` which is not optimal.

Most Linux systems run *systemd* so I assume this system is running *systemd*.

[*systemd* remounts `/`  as *shared* mount instead of the Linux kernel's default of *private*](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/commit/?id=b3ac5f8cb98757416d8660023d6564a7c411f0a0). See the kernel documentation about mount propagation here: [Shared Subtrees](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt). That means that when later additional mounts are added (or removed and readded) over `/` they get also automatically mounted over `/mnt/src` by the propagation mechanism, and **since it's *shared* (rather than *slave*) attempting to unmount them from `/mnt/src` will also unmount them from `/`**, either failing (because in use by processes) or causing possible harm if succeeeding (they will also disappear from their original mountpoint).

### What should have been done?

Always do such bind mounts using the *private* propagation option. While at it, when it's for backup purpose, also have the bind mount be (re)mounted read-only:

```
mount --bind --make-private -o ro / /mnt/src
```

That way no further interaction with other *mounts* will happen and this can be unmounted at any time with a simple `umount /mnt/src` without any side effect.

### What can be done to fix the current problem?

So to do this properly without affecting the actual original mountpoints, one should set every problematic mounts as *private* so they can be unmounted without affecting the original mountpoint.

I make an example here (all as *root* user) mimicking OP's case where after having done:

```shell
# mkdir -p /mnt/src
# mount --bind -o ro / /mnt/src
```

And then later (in a place that can't be harmful):

```shell
# mkdir -p /root/intheway
# mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /root/intheway
```

leading then to:

```shell
# umount /mnt/src
umount: /mnt/src: target is busy.
```

- identify problematic mounts using [`findmnt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/findmnt.8.html):

  ```shell
  # findmnt --kernel --submounts --list -o +PROPAGATION /mnt/src
  TARGET                  SOURCE     FSTYPE  OPTIONS                        PROPAGATION
  /mnt/src                /dev/vda2  ext4    ro,relatime,errors=remount-ro  shared
  /mnt/src/root/intheway  tmpfs      tmpfs   rw,relatime,inode64            shared
  ```
- Set all such found *shared* mounts as *private*, including `/mnt/src`:

  ```shell
  # mount --make-private /mnt/src/root/intheway
  # mount --make-private /mnt/src
  ```
- unmount them (in inverse order of the order they are mounted if there are multiple depths), finishing with `/mnt/src`

  ```shell
  # umount /mnt/src/root/intheway
  # umount /mnt/src
  ```

This didn't disrupt the (shared) mount that was in the way:

```shell
# findmnt --kernel --list -o +PROPAGATION /root/intheway
TARGET         SOURCE FSTYPE OPTIONS             PROPAGATION
/root/intheway tmpfs  tmpfs  rw,relatime,inode64 shared
```

Comment: Now for the out of space error, that's an other unrelated problem or a problem that can be helped by not having these additional mounts. Also it's now easy to check if files overlayed by a mount can be made visible by doing again such bind mount the right way, (and in rw mode).

Comment: You are awesome, this covered it and I learned something.  Thank you so much for such an awesome long response!